# Zip Referenced Libraries into Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, jodatime, libraries

I have no experience with package structure. I added two external libraries (from Joda) to my eclipse project. The code makes use of the libraries with no problems. However, when I export the Archived File and open it on another computer, the libraries are no where to be found. Much sadness.The error looks like a little red exclamation point next to my project in the package explorer. Checkboxes next to the libraries have been checked/applied.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Right click on your project
- Navigate to build paths -> configure build path
- In order and export tab check whether the library is in the list or not
- If it is not selected, tick the Checkbox and click apply

Comment: I really liked that answer, but there must be something additionally wrong.

Comment: So you mean to say that the libraries are already checked in the order and export tab??

Comment: Does these library are in the project or you just linked them from outside the project???

Comment: They are checked in the order and export tab. I attempted to 'add them as external jars.' But, I find that there is a path to my Desktop (where I originally downloaded the libraries) that can be seen when I hover near the libraries in my package explorer. That means that I merely linked to them, but didn't add them into my project???

Comment: First remove your libraries from build path, then create a folder "library" or "libs" or anything you want in your project, copy and paste libraries into that folder, lastly add them into build path

Comment: Your the best! Thank you soooooo much.

Comment: They show up in my Package Explorer, but when I export the project, there are no libraries. Perhaps there is a bug with eclipse neon. Thanks for help.

Comment: I am also using same eclipse neon so exactly what happens when you export as a jar?? Is it runnable jar?? how do you export the project?? Is it not opening??  Provide error trace so I can point you the right direction

Comment: Try running executable jar from command prompt which provides error trace

Comment: It runs when I export as a .jar. OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Someone told me that I need to export it as a executable jar.